# Softkeypad cause truncation of Android EditText.setError() message in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-2.3-gingerbread

When I'm using edittext.setError("Please fill data in required field") in android, it works fine until the keyboard keypad comes up and the error gets pushed above the edittext, after which it does not display the whole error message. Any help would be appreciated. Following are the images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
on activity tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`
corrected the issue for me. Hope it help.